# Adding Wordpress filters conditionally / for one page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, add-filter

I have two menus, a primary and secondary, I want to add `data-scroll=''` attributes to only the main menu. I am sucessfully adding the attribute to all menus with the current code:

```
function add_data_scroll( $atts, $item, $args ) {

    $atts['data-scroll'] = ' ';
    return $atts;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_data_scroll', 10, 3 );
```

How to I add this filter conditionally to my main menu? The main menu is also only used on the front page - so this maybe a good way to target it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the example for the [`wp_nav_menu_args` filter on wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_nav_menu_args).

You need to set the `theme_location` parameter when defining your menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

In your filter you can then do:

```
function add_data_scroll( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if( 'primary' == $args['theme_location'] )
    {
        $atts['data-scroll'] = ' ';
        return $atts;
    }

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_data_scroll', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. I've added this code and I am now getting the following message: 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'